# Javascript Animate Bottom

Tags: javascript, intervals, animated

I'm trying to make a div float up from the bottom of the page using only javascript (NO JQUERY).

I have a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/H7GSF/

It moves up once but won't iterate to create an 'animation'.

HTML

```
<div id="block"></div>​
```

CSS

```
#block { position: fixed; background: red; width: 100px; height: 20px; bottom: 0; }​
```

JS

```
b = 0;
el = document.getElementById('block');
setInterval(function(){
    b+=10;
    el.setAttribute('style','bottom:'+(b)+'px;');
},20);​
```

Comment: Always put the relevant code along with jsfiddle link.

Comment: @Shmiddty - Let me revise that for you: "Looks like you forgot `+=`, so it's not adding against itself", but being a dick is cool too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not updating the value of `bottom`. Its always `10`

Try this,

```
b = 0;
el = document.getElementById('block');
setInterval(function(){
    b+=10;
    el.setAttribute('style','bottom:'+(b)+'px;');
},20);​
```

Comment: you can also set just bottom attribute el.style.bottom = b +'px';

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/H7GSF/1/

Just use

```
b = 0;
el = document.getElementById('block');
setInterval(function(){
    b+=10;
    el.setAttribute('style','bottom:'+b+'px;');
},20);
```

The problem was that `b` was constant!

Moreover, I think its better modifying the style using `style` property instead of `style` attribute (and it's shorter):

```
el.style.bottom=b+'px;'
```

And be aware that if you use the `style` attribute, you remove previous styles added to the element using both the attributte and the property `style`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!
http://jsfiddle.net/thewebguy/H7GSF/2/

You just need to alter the `b` variable